# pandas map and join multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need to pass 5 columns from my pandas df and join the resulting 5 values into the same row.

```
df.head()

           BP    Pain   Pulse    RR   Temp
0     111/111       9      75    13   97.1
1        None    None    None    18     98
2      164/87       6      79    15   None
3      120/72       5      77    18     97
```

Another module that is called `VSCleaner`

```
VSCleaner.CleanVSSET(df.BP, df.Pain, df.Pulse, df.RR, df.Temp)
```

will return something like

```
{'BP': '120/40', 'Pain': 2, 'Pulse': 180, 'RR': 18, 'Temp': 66.0}, True
```

I need to pass each df row into that function and the values in the resulting dict and bool to be inserted in the same row `(cleaned_BP, cleaned_Pain, cleaned_Pulse, cleaned_RR, cleaned_Temp , BOOL isCleaned)` and run this in all my df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way i've found:

```
>>> def CleanVSSET_apply(x):
        # in my case CleanVSSET just returns the same values
        d = CleanVSSET(*x.values)
        r = d[0]
        r['Cleaned'] = d[1]
        return pd.Series(r)
>>>
>>> df_cleaned = df.apply(CleanVSSET_apply, axis=1)
        BP Cleaned  Pain Pulse  RR  Temp
0  111/111    True     9    75  13  97.1
1     None    True  None  None  18    98
2   164/87    True     6    79  15  None
3   120/72    True     5    77  18    97

>>> pd.merge(df, df_cleaned, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['', 'cleaned'])
        BP  Pain Pulse  RR  Temp BP_cleaned Cleaned Pain_cleaned  \
0  111/111     9    75  13  97.1    111/111    True            9   
1     None  None  None  18    98       None    True         None   
2   164/87     6    79  15  None     164/87    True            6   
3   120/72     5    77  18    97     120/72    True            5   

  Pulse_cleaned  RR_cleaned Temp_cleaned  
0            75          13         97.1  
1          None          18           98  
2            79          15         None  
3            77          18           97
```

Comment: `CleanVSSET` has to has the values in specific order. `(*x.values)` from the df does not guarantee that

Comment: well you can easily change it to `vscleaner.CleanVSSet(x['Pulse'], x['RR'], x['Pain'], x['Temp'], x['BP'])`

Comment: i used your answer it was faster

Answer (score 0):

That's what I did at last it works and returns desired output.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cleaned_dict, isSwapped = vscleaner.CleanVSSet(row['Pulse'], row['RR'], row['Pain'], row['Temp'], row['BP'])
    df.loc[index, 'Pulse_cleaned'] = cleaned_dict['Pulse']
    df.loc[index, 'RR_cleaned'] = cleaned_dict['RR']
    df.loc[index, 'Pain_cleaned'] = cleaned_dict['Pain']
    df.loc[index, 'Temp_cleaned'] = cleaned_dict['Temp']
    df.loc[index, 'BP_cleaned'] = cleaned_dict['BP']
    df.loc[index, 'isSwapped'] = isSwapped
```